# Корректное отображение html css в Discord Python

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, email

Бот должен отправлять новые письма пользователю с его почты. Есть полученный код письма. Можно ли отобразить сообщение так же как мы видим его в почтовом сервисе. Может быть нужно правильно настроить embed?

Comment: Зависит от того, из чего состоит данное письмо. Discord поддерживает только Markdown разметку, это базовые компоненты форматирование текста: жирный, курсив, подчеркивание, ссылка, заголовки, да вроде и все. Если вот ваше письмо состоит из подобного, то вы сможете его перевести в формат дискорда, ну а если нет, то советую изобрести специальный для дискорда шаблон письма, ну или изобретать костыли по типу снимка письма и отправки его в виде картинки.

Comment: Был варинт использовать html2text, но он содержит не все нужные мне элементы. Сожердание письма будет сложным: рассылки от крупных сервисов на подобие GitHub, Yandex. Попробую html2image. Может поможет